# Parabola with turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have to finish the other 2 quadrants, currently struggling with the usage of x and y. My limitations are the usage of a window 700,700 and a separation of 10 pixels between every line.

[image]

As for now, this is my code:

```
def dibujar_linea(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x1,y1)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(x2,y2)
    
    
def dibujarParabola():   
    
    turtle.reset()
    
    for y in range (350,-1,-10):
        color = ["yellow", "red", "pink", "white", "orange", "green", "blue"]
        turtle.pencolor(color[y%7])
        x = y - 350
        dibujar_linea(0,y,x,0)    
    turtle.left(90)

    for y in range (-1,-349,10): 
        color_2 = ["cyan", "red", "pink", "white", "orange", "green", "blue"]
        turtle.pencolor(color_2[y%7])
        x = y - 350
        dibujar_linea(y,0,0,x)
    turtle.left(180)  
    
    for y in range (-1,349,10):
        color_2 = ["cyan", "red", "pink", "white", "orange", "green", "blue"]
        turtle.pencolor(color_2[y%7])
        x = y - 350
        dibujar_linea(y,0,0,x)
    turtle.right(90)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your middle loop, `for y in range (-1,-349,10)` is broken due to the `range` specification.  Your other two loops are fine.  You just need to rework copies of them to cover the area in question.

Below, I've reworked, and simplified, your code to finish the drawing, but also to synchronize the colors (in the finished pattern) and rearrange the loops to show a continuous, contiguous turtle motion instead of jumping around:

```
import turtle

COLORS = ['red', 'pink', 'white', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']

def dibujar_linea(x, y):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(x, 0)

def dibujarParabola():
    for y in range(-350, -1, 10):
        turtle.pencolor(COLORS[-y//10 % len(COLORS)])
        x = y + 350
        dibujar_linea(x, y)

    for y in range(0, 351, 10):
        turtle.pencolor(COLORS[y//10 % len(COLORS)])
        x = 350 - y
        dibujar_linea(x, y)

    for y in range(350, -1, -10):
        turtle.pencolor(COLORS[y//10 % len(COLORS)])
        x = y - 350
        dibujar_linea(x, y)

    for y in range(0, -351, -10):
        turtle.pencolor(COLORS[-y//10 % len(COLORS)])
        x = -350 - y
        dibujar_linea(x, y)

turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

dibujarParabola()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

[image]